# Intent set by NotificationManager is not reflected in activity's onResume()

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I have a broadcast receiver that, upon receiving something, will create a pending intent, package it with some data, and use it to create a notification with NotificationManager.  The activity that is specified in the pending intent, when NotificationManager resumes the activity, always reads out the original pending intent's data -- it never reads out any new data when set by subsequent onReceive()'s from the broadcast receiver.  Here's a snippet from the broadcast receiver:

```
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if( action.equals( "someaction" ) ) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int icon = R.drawable.icon;
        CharSequence tickerText = context.getString( R.string.tickerText );
        CharSequence contentTitle = context.getString( R.string.contentTitle );
        CharSequence contentText = context.getString( R.string.contentText );
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent( context, MyActivity.class );

        Log.d( TAG, "Creating notification with data = " + intent.getStringExtra( "somestring" ) );
        notificationIntent.putExtra( "somestring", intent.getStringExtra( "somestring" ) );
        notificationIntent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP );
        notificationIntent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( context, 0, notificationIntent, 0 );
        Notification notification = new Notification( icon, tickerText, now );
        NotificationManager notificationmgr = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL |
                              Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND |
                              Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo( context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent );
        notificationmgr.cancelAll();
        notificationmgr.notify( 0, notification );
    }
}
```

and here's that of the activity:

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String somestring = intent.getStringExtra( "somestring" );

    Log.d( TAG, "onStart(), somestring = " + somestring );
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String somestring = intent.getStringExtra( "somestring" );

    Log.d( TAG, "onResume(), somestring = " + somestring );
}

protected void onNewIntent( Intent intent ) {
    Log.d( TAG, "onNewIntent(), intent = " + intent );
    super.onNewIntent( intent );
    setIntent( intent );
}
```

So here's the scenario:
From the home screen, my receiver receives some intent with, say, *somestring* set to "hello world".  The notification bar shows the notification, I slide down the notification bar, and tap on the notification to launch (create or resume) the activity.  The activity reads out "hello world" correctly.  I leave the activity in the foreground or background it with the home key.  The second time around my broadcast receiver receives, say, "hello again" as *somestring*.  It again creates the notification, this time with "hello again", except when resuming the activity via the notification, I see in the debug that *neither* getIntent() nor onNewIntent() reflects the updated value of *somestring* (i.e. "hello again").  That is, it's still holding onto the old value of "hello world".

Any ideas?  I can't seem to find a way to force an update of the intent's data.  Any help is appreciated; thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Fixed it.  When creating the pending intent, one should pass `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` as such:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( context, 0,
     notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
```

Comment: I found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168484/pendingintent-works-correctly-for-the-first-notification-but-incorrectly-for-the
Although I don't see how setAction( somerandomnumber ) is necessary

Comment: I tried this PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT ); but Still my Listview is not getting updated. Do I have to make any changes in the ListView activity also?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a couple of hours today, you can ALSO set the flag to 0 if you don't need it! I don't really need it, so helped me :)! Hope it helps someone else!