# Why does AppWidgetManager update Intent of all RemoteViews for Widgets?

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, android-widget

I have a widget defined in my Android app that maps to a specific lightswitch which is chosen by a configuration Activity. Each instance of the widget can map to a different lightswitch and tapping the widget toggles the light on and off. 
Here's the code from the Activity that sets up the widget:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() != R.id.action_choose) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.device_widget);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widgetOnOffButton, android.R.drawable.star_big_off);

    SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MyWidgetService.WIDGET_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    prefs.putInt(MyWidgetService.WIDGET_DEVICE_ID + Integer.toString(mAppWidgetId), mDeviceId);
    prefs.apply();

    Intent clickIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MyWidgetProvider.class);
    clickIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
    clickIntent.putExtra(MyWidgetService.ON_LEVEL, 100);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetOnOffButton, pendingIntent);

    mAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, remoteViews);
}
```

I've verified that the mAppWidgetId is the new ID for the widget. Here's my AppWidgetProvider's code, I use the onReceive method so I can access the extras in the Intent, but I have an onUpdate and onDelete defined for any Intents that fall outside the normal click conditions:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();
    int widgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
    int onLevel = intent.getIntExtra(MyWidgetService.ON_LEVEL, -1);

    if(action == AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE && widgetId > -1 && onLevel > -1) {

        Intent newIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), WishFullWidgetService.class);
        newIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
        newIntent.putExtra(MyWidgetService.ON_LEVEL, onLevel);
        context.startService(newIntent);
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    Intent resultValue = new Intent();
    resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
    finish();

    return true;
}
```

And this is the code from MyWidgetService. Each time a widget is clicked, I reset its OnClickPendingIntent with its own WidgetId and OnLevel, however all the widgets fire off the PendingIntent with the latest widget's ID and OnLevel.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
    int widgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
    int onLevel = intent.getIntExtra(ON_LEVEL, -1);

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.device_widget);
    Intent clickIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), WishFullWidgetProvider.class);
    clickIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);

    if(onLevel > 0) {
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widgetOnOffButton, android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
        clickIntent.putExtra(ON_LEVEL, 0);
    } else {
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widgetOnOffButton, android.R.drawable.star_big_off);
        clickIntent.putExtra(ON_LEVEL, 100);
    }

    if(onLevel > -1) {
        int deviceId = mPrefs.getInt(WIDGET_DEVICE_ID + Integer.toString(widgetId), -1);
        sendMessageToDevice(onLevel, deviceId);
    }

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetOnOffButton, pendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);

    stopSelf();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

At this point, if I have Widget 1 and Widget 2, clicking Widget 1 will fire the Intent containing the ID and OnLevel of Widget 2. How can I update the OnClickPendingIntent of each widget independently without the newest one overwriting the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a unique int as the first flag (second parameter) of the pendingIntent, preferably widgetID.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), uniqueID, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

This will cause android to not override the existing pendingIntent, but create a new one.

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168484/pendingintent-works-correctly-for-the-first-notification-but-incorrectly-for-the) to a different post with a similar problem.